# Navigation bar to the center

Tags: html, css, web, menu

I have designed a header that is center of the page with logo and some links. Below the header I have navigation menu which is aligned to the left of the page. I want the navigation menu to the center of the page that is as below the header.How do I achieve this? Here is the code link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ihamG/. If i add margin 0 auto; menu gets collapsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following:

```
#nav    
- text-align:center;

#nav > li
- display:inline-block;
- *display:inline; /*IE7*/
- *zoom:1; /*IE7*/
```

And remove:

```
#nav > li
- display:inline;
- float: left;
```

Updated, Forked codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dbqzw/